# Psql - generate series with running total

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, cumulative-sum

I have the following table:

```
create table account_info(
    id int not null unique,
    creation_date date,
    deletion_date date,
    gather boolean)
```

Adding sample data to it:

```
insert into account_info(id,creation_date,deletion_date,gather)
values(1,'2019-09-10',null,true),
(2,'2019-09-12',null,true),
(3,'2019-09-14','2019-10-08',true),
(4,'2019-09-15','2019-09-18',true),
(5,'2019-09-22',null,false),
(6,'2019-09-27','2019-09-29',true),
(7,'2019-10-04','2019-10-17',false),
(8,null,'2019-10-20',true),
(9,'2019-10-12',null,true),
(10,'2019-10-18',null,true)
```

I would like to see how many accounts have been added grouped by week and how many accounts have been deleted grouped by week.

I have tried the following:

```
select dd, count(distinct ai.id) as created ,count(distinct ai2.id) as deleted

from generate_series('2019-09-01'::timestamp, 
                     '2019-10-21'::timestamp, '1 week'::interval) dd
left join account_info ai on ai.creation_date::DATE <= dd::DATE
left join account_info ai2 on ai2.deletion_date::DATE <=dd::DATE
where ai.gather is true
and ai2.gather is true
group by dd
order by dd asc
```

This produces the following output:

```
 dd          | Created | Deleted |
+------------+---------+---------+
| 2019-09-22 |       4 |       1 |
| 2019-09-29 |       5 |       2 |
| 2019-10-06 |       5 |       2 |
| 2019-10-13 |       6 |       3 |
| 2019-10-20 |       7 |       4 |
```

This output shows me the the running total of how many have been created and how many been deleted.

I would like to see however something like this:

```
+------------+---------+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
|     dd     | Created | Deleted | Total Sum Created | Total Sum Deleted |
+------------+---------+---------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 2019-09-22 | 4       | 1       |                 4 |                 1 |
| 2019-09-29 | 1       | 1       |                 5 |                 2 |
| 2019-10-06 | NULL    | NULL    |                 5 |                 2 |
| 2019-10-13 | 1       | 1       |                 6 |                 3 |
| 2019-10-20 | 1       | 1       |                 7 |                 4 |
```

I get an error message, when trying to sum up the `created` and `deleted`columns in psql. As I cannot nest aggregate functions.

Comment: Hi. FYI You just deleted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58476634/3404097). Deleting posts can count towards being banned from asking question. When possible, edit posts rather than deleting (but don't invalidate reasonable posted answers). Also when improved you may get downvotes removed and/or replaced by upvotes. PS Wanting to nest aggregates is a faq. Also, recall that on your other question I said to show one sum calculation. Not only would that show "research effort", you could compare that to your eventual goal to get unstuck.

Comment: You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. When you get output you don't understand, ask re *that error*; ask re your overall goal later in a new post. Also a syntax error is almost certainly a faq. Google it. PS When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will heed them going forward. I appreciate your help from a meta point of view. I have also noted your comments regarding the debugging fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lateral join and aggregation is soooo well suited to this problem.  If you are content with the weeks in the data:

```
select date_trunc('week', dte) as week,
       sum(is_create) as creates_in_week,
       sum(is_delete) as deletes_in_week,
       sum(sum(is_create)) over (order by min(v.dte)) as running_creates,
       sum(sum(is_delete)) over (order by min(v.dte)) as running_deletes
from account_info ai cross join lateral
     (values (ai.creation_date, 1, 0), (ai.deletion_date, 0, 1)
     ) v(dte, is_create, is_delete)
where v.dte is not null and ai.gather
group by week
order by week;
```

If you want it for a specified set of weeks:

```
select gs.wk,
       sum(v.is_create) as creates_in_week,
       sum(v.is_delete) as deletes_in_week,
       sum(sum(v.is_create)) over (order by min(v.dte)) as running_creates,
       sum(sum(v.is_delete)) over (order by min(v.dte)) as running_deletes
from generate_series('2019-09-01'::timestamp, 
                     '2019-10-21'::timestamp, '1 week'::interval) gs(wk) left join
    ( account_info ai cross join lateral
      (values (ai.creation_date, 1, 0), (ai.deletion_date, 0, 1)
      ) v(dte, is_create, is_delete)
    )
    on v.dte >= gs.wk and
       v.dte < gs.wk + interval '1 week'
where dte is not null and ai.gather
group by gs.wk
order by gs.wk;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0cf8a035c6fdeba4fcea25a10bac85bc) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @Nick . . . It does with the `gather` filter.

Answer (score 2):

You could just turn your existing query to a subquery and use `lag()` to compute the difference between consecutive records:

```
select 
    dd,
    created - coalesce(lag(created) over(order by dd), 0) created,
    deleted - coalesce(lag(deleted) over(order by dd), 0) deleted,
    created total_sum_created,
    deleted total_sum_deleted
from (
    select 
        dd, 
        count(distinct ai.id) as created ,
        count(distinct ai2.id) as deleted
    from 
        generate_series(
            '2019-09-01'::timestamp, 
            '2019-10-21'::timestamp, 
            '1 week'::interval
        ) dd
        left join account_info ai 
            on ai.creation_date::DATE <= dd::DATE and ai.gather is true
        left join account_info ai2 
            on ai2.deletion_date::DATE <=dd::DATE and ai2.gather is true
    group by dd
) x
order by dd asc
```

I moved conditions  `ai[2].gather = true` to the `on` side of the `join`: putting these conditions in the `where` clause basically turns you `left join`s to `inner join`s.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bvFg33i79vjjdZiwns3BYU/1)**:

```
| dd                       | created | deleted | total_sum_created | total_sum_deleted |
| ------------------------ | ------- | ------- | ----------------- | ----------------- |
| 2019-09-01T00:00:00.000Z | 0       | 0       | 0                 | 0                 |
| 2019-09-08T00:00:00.000Z | 0       | 0       | 0                 | 0                 |
| 2019-09-15T00:00:00.000Z | 4       | 0       | 4                 | 0                 |
| 2019-09-22T00:00:00.000Z | 0       | 1       | 4                 | 1                 |
| 2019-09-29T00:00:00.000Z | 1       | 1       | 5                 | 2                 |
| 2019-10-06T00:00:00.000Z | 0       | 0       | 5                 | 2                 |
| 2019-10-13T00:00:00.000Z | 1       | 1       | 6                 | 3                 |
| 2019-10-20T00:00:00.000Z | 1       | 1       | 7                 | 4                 |
```

---

Another option would be to use `lag()` in combination with `generate_series()` to generate a list of date ranges. Then you can do just one join on the original table, and do conditional aggregation in the outer query:

```
select
    dd,
    count(distinct case 
        when ai.creation_date::date <= dd::date and ai.creation_date::date > lag_dd::date 
        then ai.id 
    end) created,
    count(distinct case 
        when ai.deletion_date::date <= dd::date and ai.deletion_date::date > lag_dd::date 
        then ai.id 
    end) deleted,
    count(distinct case 
        when ai.creation_date::date <= dd::date 
        then ai.id 
    end) total_sum_created,
    count(distinct case 
        when ai.deletion_date::date <= dd::date 
        then ai.id 
    end) total_sum_deleted
from 
    (
        select dd, lag(dd) over(order by dd) lag_dd
        from generate_series(
            '2019-09-01'::timestamp, 
            '2019-10-21'::timestamp, 
            '1 week'::interval
        ) dd
    ) dd
    left join account_info ai on ai.gather is true
group by dd
order by dd
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bvFg33i79vjjdZiwns3BYU/2)**

Comment: Of course you are right with moving the condition to the `on` statement. Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the results you want using a series of CTEs to build up the data tables:

```
with dd as
(select *
 from generate_series('2019-09-01'::timestamp, 
                      '2019-10-21'::timestamp, '1 week'::interval) d),
ddl as
(select d, coalesce(lag(d) over (order by d), '1970-01-01'::timestamp) as pd
 from dd),
counts as
(select d, count(distinct ai.id) as created, count(distinct ai2.id) as deleted
 from ddl
 left join account_info ai on ai.creation_date::DATE > ddl.pd::DATE AND ai.creation_date::DATE <= ddl.d::DATE AND ai.gather is true
 left join account_info ai2 on ai2.deletion_date::DATE > ddl.pd::DATE AND ai2.deletion_date::DATE <= ddl.d::DATE AND ai2.gather is true
 group by d)
select d, created, deleted,
       sum(created) over (rows unbounded preceding) as "total created",
       sum(deleted) over (rows unbounded preceding) as "total deleted"
from counts
order by d asc
```

Note that the `gather` condition needs to be part of the `left join` to avoid turning those into inner joins.

Output:

```
d                       created     deleted     total created   total deleted
2019-09-01 00:00:00     0           0           0               0
2019-09-08 00:00:00     0           0           0               0
2019-09-15 00:00:00     4           0           4               0
2019-09-22 00:00:00     0           1           4               1
2019-09-29 00:00:00     1           1           5               2
2019-10-06 00:00:00     0           0           5               2
2019-10-13 00:00:00     1           1           6               3
2019-10-20 00:00:00     1           1           7               4
```

Note this query gives the results for the week ending with `d`. If you want results for the week starting with `d`, the `lag` can be changed to `lead`. You can see this in my demo.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5712175d4ac89de4f89aff71293976a9)

Comment: Thank you very much for the in detail solution. I appreciate it. I have to be honest I need to read through the psql documentation and why you have used the rows unbounded preceding statement. But,@Nick, thank you !

Comment: @user12121022 no worries. the rows unbounded preceding just tells the query to sum up all rows with lower values of `d` (since the result set is ordered by `d`)